# Thread safe Queue

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm using a Queue with the concurrent.futures library in python 2.7. When I run this code snippet below it's not uncommon for it to print four 1s. I want the thread queue to be a way to share data but it does not seem to be thread safe. How can I make it thread safe?

```
q = Queue.Queue()

def test():
    x = q.get(True)
    print x

def thread_pool():
    for x in [1,2,3,4,5]:
        q.put(x)
    #with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
    for x in range(5):
        executor.submit(test)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a thread pool.  It's a process pool.  If you want to share objects between processes, you need to use [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) instead (and possibly switch your whole program over to using [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool); the documentation is unclear on this point).  If you want to use threads instead of processes, you need to use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of `ProcessPoolExecutor`.